# A question regarding critical points

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

We have the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-5)}$. I want to find the critical points so I differentiated it and I got $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{(x-5)^2}$. Now I want to find the critical points so I have to find $f'(c)=0$ and $f'(c)= \text{does not exist}$. So How can I find them both in this situation?

Comment: Are you given an interval?

Comment: No .. the original question says Is 5 a critcical number ? So i thought of finding the whole points but i didn't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that $f$ has no critical points.

If you are trying to find the critical points in order to find extrema of the function $f$, note that $f$ has no upper or lower bound on $\mathbb{R}$ (and moreover, it is undefined at $x=5$).

However, if you are given an interval of the form $[a,b]$ such that $5\notin [a,b]$, the nonexistence of critical points implies that you only need to check $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ (the endpoints) to find extrema.